# Python Regular Expression [\d+]

Tags: python, regex

I am working on regular expression python, I came across this problem.

A valid mobile number is a ten digit number starting with a 7,8 or 9.
my solution to this was :

```
if len(x)==10 and re.search(r'^[7|8|9]+[\d+]$',x):
```

for which i was getting error. later I changed it to

```
if len(x)==10 and re.search(r'^[7|8|9]+\d+$',x):
```

for which all test cases passed. I want to know what the difference between using and not using `[]` for `\d+` in regex ?

Thanks

Comment: `[\d]+` would have been correct, `[\d+]` means one charatcer thats either a number or a plus. Also remove the `|`s from the character class, as they are treated as just literal `|`

Comment: I think you need to read a regexp tutorial. You seem to be using `[]` where you really want `()`.

Comment: `[]` looks for a single character inside. Eg: `[abc]` look for `a`, `b` or `c`.

Answer (score 8):

`[\d+]` = one digit (`0-9`) or `+` character.

`\d+` = one or more digits.

Comment: Escape sequences work inside `[]`, so it's a digit or `+`.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do:

```
if re.search(r'^[789]\d{9}$', x):
```

letting the regex handle the `len(x)==10` part by using explicit lengths instead of unbounded repetitions.

Answer (score 1):

I think a general explanation about `[]` and `+` is what you need.

`[]` will match with a single character specified inside.
Eg: `[qwe]` will match with `q`, `w` or `e`.

**If you want to enter an expression inside `[]`, you need to use it as `[^ expression]`.**

`+` will match the preceding element one or more times.
Eg: `qw+e` matches `qwe`, `qwwe`, `qwwwwe`, etc...
Note: this is different from `*` as `*` matches preceding element zero or more times. i.e. `qw*e` matches `qe` as well.

`\d` matches with numerals. (not just `0-9`, but numerals from other language scripts as well.)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about complexity but this is also works:

```
if (len(x)==10 and "789"==x[1:4]):
```